# php problem to execute CutyCapt command

Tags: php, command-line

i'm having this problem

```
sh: CutyCapt: Permission denied
```

my php code is

```
<?php 
       echo exec('CutyCapt --url=http://www.google.com --out=/var/www/google.png --javascript=on 2>&1');
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

When calling an executable from PHP, it is called with the permissions of the user PHP runs as (often the Apache server, for example).

That user account does not have permission to call that executable - probably because it belongs to a different user, and has the "executable" bit only for that user or group.

That's all that can be said for sure without more information.

Comment: so any idea to give apache permission to execute CutyCapt?

Answer (score 0):

CutyCapt needs the screen to make a screenshot. Pass it to your command:

```php
$command = "xvfb-run --server-args='-screen 0, 1024x768x24' cutycapt --url=$href --out=$img_path --min-width=1800 --min-height=1200 --max-wait=10000 2>&1";
$output = shell_exec( $command );
var_dump( $output);
```